# Saving a players HAND in the database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

So I want to add a **playerID** (which is in a different table called **Player**) to a table (**PlayersHand**) also I would like to add the CardsID, CardsName, and typeOfDeck to that table (**PlayersHand**).

i've tried using RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to get the PlayersID as it's an auto increment column in my table **Player**

the other information i need i could get by looping through a list of players to get their hand and cardID, name, decktype.

```
public void saveHand(List<Player> players) throws SQLException{

    try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectie.JDBC_URL);
            PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_KAARTEN_IN_HAND)) {

        /*  private static final String INSERT_KAARTEN_IN_HAND = "INSERT INTO ID222177_g74.KaartenSpeler (idPlayer, idCard, cardName, deck)"
        + "VALUES (?,?,?, ?)";*/
        int count = 0;
        int teller = 0;
        for (Player s : players) {
            do {
                query.setInt(1, getPlayerID());
                query.setInt(2, s.getHand().get(teller).getKaartID());
                query.setString(3, s.getHand().get(teller).getNaam());
                query.setString(4, s.getHand().get(teller).getSoort());    query.addBatch();
                teller++;
                count++;
                if (count % 100 == 0 || count == players.size()) {
                    query.executeBatch();
                }
            } while (teller <= s.getHand().size());
        }
    }
}
```

---

In another query i use this to get the playerid

```
try (ResultSet generatedKeys = query.getGeneratedKeys()) {
    if (generatedKeys.next()) {
        setPlayerID(generatedKeys.getInt(1));
    }
```

basically a player can only hold 5 cards, or less, i want to save those in the database. so for each player i want to save all his cards.

now i get 1 player and like 3 cards if he has 4 in his hand. but then it stops and doesn't do the other players.

so it should be like

```
PLayer 1 card1 cardName decktype
PLayer 1 card2 cardName decktype
PLayer 1 card3 cardName decktype
PLayer 1 card4 cardName decktype

PLayer 2 card1 cardName decktype
PLayer 2 card2 cardName decktype
PLayer 2 card3 cardName decktype
PLayer 2 card4 cardName decktype

PLayer 3 card1 cardName decktype
PLayer 3 card2 cardName decktype
PLayer 3 card3 cardName decktype
PLayer 3 card4 cardName decktype
```

Comment: Your `Player` class should contain the id so that you can do `s.getId()` in the `for` loop in the `saveHand` method. The question is why it isn't already? Are the players already stored in the database or are you only saving the hands?

Comment: the players are already stored in the database, in a seperate table for the players itself. when the player choses to save it will, first save details about the game, then the player information and it will create an auto increment ID in the table of player. and that is also linked to the gameID, then after the players and game stuff has been saved it's supposed to save the current hand of the players.

Comment: So you should have access to the ID as part of the Player class then? If not you should look into having the auto increment id return when doing INSERT on the player in the database

Comment: yeah i could be able to acces it. i'll try that out.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i'm using RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to return the Auto increment value but i don't add 1 player at a time i'm looping through a list of players and insert them in the database. when i want to set the returned key to my player object it only returns for example when i insert 3 players it would only return 3 and set my last player to ID 3 instead of player 1 to 1 and so on

Comment: Are you sure 3 is for the last id and not a counter for the number of rows inserted?

Comment: it would give the last ID created so the last auto incremented value, that he would return. but not the other ones.